# How to login AWS with email/access key/security key

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have got AWS account with the info email address/access key/security key, without any other password, i could not find where to login AWS services,such as EC2 etc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The email address and password are used to log in to the Amazon account through the web site including the AWS Console:

> https://console.aws.amazon.com

If you don't have the password associated with that email address, then you will need to have access to the email account so that you can generate and receive a password reset email.

The access key id and secret access key are one way you can access AWS functions through the API and some AWS command line tools and third party services.  Exactly how you enter or use these depends on what tools you are using to access AWS features.

There are a number of other credentials AWS uses including an X.509 certificate and private key.  These are similar to the access key id and secret access key, but

I've written an article which explains some of the different AWS credentials and how they are used: http://alestic.com/2009/11/ec2-credentials

Comment: @ Eric Hammond, thanks~ I want to deploy one Tomcat application on EC2, only use S3, so do you have some good suggestion for the suitable AMI?

Comment: That sounds like a completely new question you could ask.  My general advice is to start with a generic AMI from a trusted source using your favorite distro, then install and customize from there.

Comment: Hi @Eric,i need to login and signup using aws into my ios application,what are the steps needed to do this,would you please send some reference..!!!-Thanks.